# Missing delimiter

Tags: errors

I get an error when I type this

```
$[x] = \{n.x \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Note, primeiramente, que $x \neq 0$ (caso isso acontecesse, teríamos $[x] = \{0 \}$, o que não ocorre).
```

and also this

```
Mostre que $(\mathbb Z_p^*, \cdot)$ é isomorfo à $\left(\mathbb Z _ {p-1}\right , +)$.
```

In both cases, it says there's a missing delimiter.
There aren't any errors in the output, though; it looks exactly how I wanted it to look, but I wanted to understand what error is that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.sx.  It's usually more helpful to put code fragments into a complete minimal document with `\documentclass{} ... ` etc. and the packages needed to reproduce the problem (here, e.g. you need the `amsfonts` package).  There is no problem with your first fragment. For the second you need the `\right` to be immediately before the closing `)`.

Comment: Thanks. There's no error in the second fragment anymore.

Comment: @FrancieleDaltoé: If there is no error in the second fragment and *only* the first, then you're not providing enough context.

Comment: Oh, actually I now realized the error was because of a phrase I wrote before the first one.

Comment: @FrancieleDaltoé: Hmmm, unless you update the question to show the relevant parts, it really has no value at the moment, and we can close it.

Comment: Alright, my problem is already solved.

Answer (score 2):

Few points: `n.x` → `n\cdot x`, `\mathbb z` → `\mathbb{z}`. Further, in those places, you won't need `\left` and `\right` at all. Simply use the `(` and `)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  $[x] = \{n\cdot x \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Note, primeiramente, que $x \neq 0$ (caso isso acontecesse, teríamos $[x] = \{0\}$, o que não ocorre).

Mostre que $(\mathbb{Z}_p^*, \cdot)$ é isomorfo à $(\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}, +)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]